# Android ViewPager set View visible on scroll

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` that has certain `TextView` elements. One of these is a "Read More" that basically disappears once the View is Scrolled Down. This functionality works.

What also I want to do is make the `TextView` re-appear as the `ViewPager` changes page. So I have added the following `Listener` to my `ViewPager`:

```
private class CustomViewPagerListener extends ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        checkIsItemFavorite();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        final TextView tv = (TextView) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.imagePager_readMore);
        if (tv != null) {
            tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv.invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
}
```

EDIT: I have to mention that this works...but not always for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Simply in  `onPageSelected` method,check if `Textview` is `GONE` then set its visibility to `VISIBLE`.So try this

```
final TextView tv = (TextView) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.imagePager_readMore);

        private class CustomViewPagerListener extends ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                checkIsItemFavorite();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                    if (tv != null) {
                    tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                }
        }
```

Comment: That simply makes the TextView disappear on Page-change. This is not what I want to do. What I want is to make the TextView re-appear on the previous page.

Comment: @ChrisGeo in onPageScrolled method chnages textview visibility to gone,and in onPageSelected set textview to visible, see my edited answer